# Don't Focus Application when it opens on Mac OS

Tags: mac, firefox

So I have some automated tests that open Firefox about 150 times in an automated fashion.

These tests take about 10 minutes to run and in the mean time, I am developing a fear of flashing screens as firefox is constantly focusing itself on startup.

Is there anyway to stop this behavior either in Firefox or in the mac system.

So in essence, when Firefox opens, can it not bring itself to the front/top?

This is not a duplicate. My question has nothing in regards to spaces in Mac OS.

Comment: Did you read also the answers? _"There is also the '-g' option to 'open' that will run programs in the 'background'..."_

Comment: There are other answers at the marked dupe that are not limited to Spaces.